# JWT SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException using RS256 PII is hidden

Tags: c#, jwt

I'm having trouble validating a JWT token signed with RS256 using Microsoft's System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt library.

This token validates just fine on [JWT.io](https://jwt.io/).

This is the error:

> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException
> IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: '[PII is hidden]'.
> Exceptions caught:
> '[PII is hidden]'.
> token: '[PII is hidden]'.

This is the sample code *(i used LinqPad, with the System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt v5.2.2 NuGet package)*:

```
void Main()
{
    var cText =
        "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" +
        "MIIBljCCAUACCQCIDMpqK7WfWDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBSMQswCQYDVQQGEwJV\n" + 
        "UzETMBEGA1UECAwKU29tZS1TdGF0ZTESMBAGA1UECgwJTHV4b3R0aWNhMRowGAYD\n" +
        "VQQLDBFMdXhvdHRpY2EgZXllY2FyZTAeFw0xODA1MjMxNTE1MjdaFw0yODA1MjAx\n" +
        "NTE1MjdaMFIxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMwEQYDVQQIDApTb21lLVN0YXRlMRIwEAYD\n" +
        "VQQKDAlMdXhvdHRpY2ExGjAYBgNVBAsMEUx1eG90dGljYSBleWVjYXJlMFwwDQYJ\n" +
        "KoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAKuMYcirPj81WBtMituJJenF0CG/HYLcAUOtWKl1\n" +
        "HchC0dM8VRRBI/HV+nZcweXzpjhX8ySa9s7kJneP0cuJiU8CAwEAATANBgkqhkiG\n" +
        "9w0BAQsFAANBAKEM8wQwlqKgkfqnNFcbsZM0RUxS+eWR9LvycGuMN7aL9M6GOmfp\n" +
        "QmF4MH4uvkaiZenqCkhDkyi4Cy81tz453tQ=\n" +
        "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

    var c = new X509Certificate2(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cText));
    var p = new TokenValidationParameters();
    p.IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (s, securityToken, identifier, parameters)
        => new[] { new X509SecurityKey(c) };
    var h = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var token = @"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJuLmNoaWVmZm8iLCJleHAiOjE1MjcyMzg4ODEsImlzcyI6Imx1eCJ9.BAaYzLwokmdKqLi6zKjGIpDXd__dZxi5PUWWHS3PSLPDYAInzPbEK8o4WxunoGD7eA0qtQNaxNpzeOc3BHrd4w";
    h.ValidateToken(token, p, out SecurityToken _);
}
```

Finally it would be nice to also know how to remove the [PII is hidden] so I can see more detail on the error. Setting the enableLoggingKnownPii and logKnownPII to true in the app.config or even the machine.config file did not seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It turns out that the KeySize for X509SecurityKey needs to be at least 1024 in length for verifying. This is not obvious from the exception, since it is hidden with the [PII is hidden] filter.

Adding the following line made the exception text a lot more useful (add to `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs`):

```
IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
```

The new exception text:

> 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: IDX10631: The 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey' for verifying cannot be smaller than '1024' bits. KeySize: '512'.

Increasing the length of the assymetric key to 1024 solved the problem.

Comment: If you are using RsaSha256 then the size should not be smaller than 2024. It throws the same error otherwise.

Comment: Hi Carlo, how did you increase the length of the key?

Comment: oh, I just figured it out. All I need to do is to put more content/words inside my secret.

Comment: Just remember to go back to the default of `false` when deploying to production. You would not want `ShowPII = true` in production.

Comment: Increasing the length of the assymetric key solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 9):

You can increase your Key length as shown below in `appsettings.json` file.

```
"Jwt": {
    "Key": "pintusharmaqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqweqwe",
    "Issuer": "pintusharma.com"
  }
```