# Identity Server 4 - IDX10630: PII is hidden

Tags: c#, rsa, identityserver4, signing

I'm fairly new to using encryption and rsa tokens and I'm trying to get IDentityServer4 to not use the developersigning, but one of my own. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
var keyInfo = new RSACryptoServiceProvider().ExportParameters(true);
var rsaSecurityKey = new RsaSecurityKey(new RSAParameters
{
    D = keyInfo.D,
    DP = keyInfo.DP,
    DQ = keyInfo.DQ,
    Exponent = keyInfo.Exponent,
    InverseQ = keyInfo.InverseQ,
    Modulus = keyInfo.Modulus,
    P = keyInfo.P,
    Q = keyInfo.Q
});

services.AddIdentityServer()
.AddSigningCredential(rsaSecurityKey)
.AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
.AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
.AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
.AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
.AddAspNetIdentity<User>();
```

However, when I run Identity Server4 and I get redirected to sign in page from another website, I get the following error:

> IDX10630: The '[PII is hidden]' for signing cannot be smaller than '[PII is hidden]' bits. KeySize: '[PII is hidden]'.
>   Parameter name: key.KeySize

I have to admit, I've been on this all weekend, trying to figure out how to use SigningCredentials and I'm not really sure what I've done wrong above.

Comment: Well, an easy fix is to just call '[PII is hidden]' followed by '[PII is hidden]',

Comment: @JamesKPolk I don't know what you mean by that

Comment: You can see what is hidden: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2186#issuecomment-407959886

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JWT SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException using RS256 PII is hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50590432/jwt-securitytokeninvalidsignatureexception-using-rs256-pii-is-hidden)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can see more details in development by adding the following to Configure() in the Startup class:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
     IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true; 
}
```

Comment: it helped a lot

Comment: how do you set it? I am using asp.net in SharePoint add-in.

Comment: It's a static property of ```IdentityModelEventSource```. That can be set anywhere you want.

Answer (score 6):

For those who are having the same problem:
The `ShowPII` configuration is set globally, it's a static property of `IdentityModelEventSource` and can be set in the Startup class, for example. Once I added it I could see that it was throwing a InvalidIssuer exception for token validation. For me it was related to how I was generating the JWT to communicate with my API (which is protected with Identity Server 4). I was generating the token over the url: `http://localhost:5002`(out side of docker-compose network) which is different them the url Identity Server issuer inside my API: `http://<<docker-service-name>>`. So, if you are using docker-compose and manage to use your Identity Server as a separated container inside the same docker-compose, be aware that your authentication should generate a token with **IDENTICAL** issuer that is used in your API.