# JWT token authentication fails with message "PII is hidden"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core, jwt

in my .net core 2.2 microservice, I try to extract claims from a JWT token to do some authorization. authentication is done on another part of the system so I don't need to do it at this point.

I am using this code in the Startup.cs:

```
  services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                var signingKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("SECRET_KEY");
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(signingKey)
                };
            });
```

On the controller I have this code:

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<CreateResponse>> Create()
    {
        var userIdClaim = HttpContext.User.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "empId").SingleOrDefault();
        return Ok($"Your User ID is {userIdClaim.Value} and you can create invoices!");
    }
```

I always get this error message and "Unauthorized" response:

> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException: IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: '[PII is hidden]'.
>   Exceptions caught:
>    '[PII is hidden]'.
>   token: '[PII is hidden]'.

Comment: Signature validation fails. Make sure the signing keys are correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JWT SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException using RS256 PII is hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50590432/jwt-securitytokeninvalidsignatureexception-using-rs256-pii-is-hidden)

Comment: also work for aspnet core 3.1

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can see the hidden details in development by adding the following to Configure() in the Startup class:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
     IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true; 
}
```

Once you have the full message check the key being used is correct for the token.

Comment: @Oofpez this works in 2.2 for me, do you have an example of it not working?

Comment: @Oofpez docs suggest it works with the latest version https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.logging.identitymodeleventsource.showpii?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: I can confirm this is working for 2.2 as well, also ensure that you have 
```using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging;```

Comment: How can I do this in an xunit unit test project?