# How to use AWS Cognito to secure a .Net Core Web API applications

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, authentication, asp.net-core-webapi, amazon-cognito

I'm new to AWS and need to secure access to a .NET Core Web API application using Cognito. I'm largely following the excellent video on YouTube by Les Jackson (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3PyUjOmuFic) but he uses Azure rather than AWS.

So far, I have a very simple API controller action that just pulls some records from SQL Server and sends a JSON response.

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<TodoItem>> Get()
        {
            var items = await context.TodoItem.ToListAsync();
            return items;
        }
```

This works fine locally in Visual Studio and also when deployed to an AWS instance using Elastic Beanstalk.

To secure the application I added to the ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs

```
    services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Audience = "App client id";
            options.Authority = "https://cognito-idp.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/Cognito User Pool id";
        });
```

And in the Configure method

```
            app.UseAuthentication();
```

I added a controller to the application just to authenticate with Cognito and get back an Access token.

```
        private const string _clientId = "App client id";
        private readonly RegionEndpoint _region = RegionEndpoint.EUWest2;

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("/api/signin")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<string>> SignIn(User user)
        {
            var cognito = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(_region);

            var request = new AdminInitiateAuthRequest
            {
                UserPoolId = "Cognito User Pool id",
                ClientId = _clientId,
                AuthFlow = AuthFlowType.ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH
            };

            request.AuthParameters.Add("USERNAME", user.Username);
            request.AuthParameters.Add("PASSWORD", user.Password);

            var response = await cognito.AdminInitiateAuthAsync(request);

            return Ok(response.AuthenticationResult);
        }
```

After a bit of messing around I've got this working locally and on AWS, returning tokens when a Cognito user name and password are POSTed using Postman, e.g.

```
{
    "accessToken": ".....",
    "expiresIn": 3600,
    "idToken": "...",
    "newDeviceMetadata": null,
    "refreshToken": "...",
    "tokenType": "Bearer"
}
```

So, I added the [Authorize] attribute to my API method, got an Access Token using the SignIn method and constructed a request in Postman that includes the Authorization HTTP header with the value "Bearer " + accessToken.

Sadly, this is not working and I can't think of anything else to try.

Using Postman requests to the application running locally in IIS Express via Visual Studio, I get the response

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20807: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. HttpResponseMessage: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]', HttpResponseMessage.Content: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
```

When the application is deployed using Elastic Beanstalk I just get a 500 Internal Server Error with no additional messages.

What am I doing wrong? I would be grateful for any help / pointers.

Doug

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JWT token authentication fails with message "PII is hidden"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55300231/jwt-token-authentication-fails-with-message-pii-is-hidden)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not too sure why, but it seems to be working OK now!

The final code I ended up with is:

In ConfigureServices, Startup.cs

```
            services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { ValidateAudience = false };
                    options.Authority = "https://cognito-idp.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/eu-west-2_xxxxxxxxx";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                });
```

In Configure, Startup.cs

```
            app.UseAuthentication();
```

In appsettings.json

```
  "AWSCognito": {
    "Region": "{Region}",
    "PoolId": "{PoolId}",
    "AppClientId": "{AppClientId}"
  }
```

When an access token is supplied in the Authorization HTTP header, calls to API methods decorated with the [Authorize] attribute succeed and                    User.Identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "username").FirstOrDefault() gives the user Id of the authenticated user.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I think this error was because the URL in Authority was wrong

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do to secure your .NET 6 APIs with Amazon Cognito.

1. Install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` NuGet package.
2. Add the following settings in `appsettings.json` file.

   ```json
   {
     .
     .
     "AppSettings": {
       "AllowedOrigions": "http://localhost:80", //change it as per your requirement, this should have a comma values
       "Cognito": {
         "AppClientId": "",
         "UserPoolId": "",
         "AWSRegion": ""
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. Add the below code after `WebApplicationBuilder` in your `Program.cs` file to read the configurations.

   ```cs
   var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

   // read configurations
   string[] allowedDomains = builder.Configuration["AppSettings:AllowedOrigions"].Split(",");
   string cognitoAppClientId = builder.Configuration["AppSettings:Cognito:AppClientId"].ToString();
   string cognitoUserPoolId = builder.Configuration["AppSettings:Cognito:UserPoolId"].ToString();
   string cognitoAWSRegion = builder.Configuration["AppSettings:Cognito:AWSRegion"].ToString();

   string validIssuer = $"https://cognito-idp.{cognitoAWSRegion}.amazonaws.com/{cognitoUserPoolId}";
   string validAudience = cognitoAppClientId;
   ```
4. Also, add the the following code in your `Program.cs` file to register necessary services.

   ```cs
   // Configure CORS
   builder.Services.AddCors(item =>
   {
       item.AddPolicy("CORSPolicy", builder =>
       {
           builder.WithOrigins(allowedDomains)
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowAnyHeader();
       });
   });

   // Register authentication schemes, and specify the default authentication scheme
   builder.Services
       .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
       .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
       {
         // Note: Authority is the address of the token-issuing authentication server.
         // The JWT bearer authentication middleware will use this URI to find and retrieve the public key that can be used to validate the token’s signature.
         // It will also confirm that the iss parameter in the token matches this URI. Hence, we don't need to specify ValidateIssuer explicitly in TokenValidationParameters.
         // See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/

           options.Authority = validIssuer;
           options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
           {
               ValidateLifetime = true,
               ValidAudience = validAudience,
               ValidateAudience = true,
           };
       });

   var app = builder.Build();
   ```
5. Add **CORS** and authentication middlewares.

   ```cs
   app.UseCors("CORSPolicy");

   app.UseAuthentication(); // resposible for constructing AuthenticationTicket objects representing the user's identity
   app.UseAuthorization();
   ```

   Note that authentication process is handled by the authentication middleware that we register using the `app.UseAuthentication()` code.
6. Create a `ProfileController` as shown below for the testing purpose.

   ```cs
   [Authorize]
   [ApiController]
   [Route("[controller]")]
   public class ProfileController : ControllerBase
   {

       [HttpGet]
       public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Get()
       {
           return User.Claims.Select(item => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(item.Type, item.Value)).ToList();
       }
   }
   ```

> **Note:** If you want to learn **Building Serverless .NET APIs using AWS Lambda, Amazon API Gateway, and Amazon Cognito**, I have created the following content regarding the same, which might be helpful.
>
> - GitHub Repository - [ankushjain358/serverless-dotnet-apis-with-amazon-cognito](https://github.com/ankushjain358/serverless-dotnet-apis-with-amazon-cognito/)
> - [Blog Post](https://coderjony.com/blogs/building-serverless-net-apis-using-aws-lambda-amazon-api-gateway-and-amazon-cognito-authentication-and-authorization?source=stackoverflow)
> - [YouTube Playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7OOStOfKPFfekur5LJFyI0e6wQB7KiJO)