# Azure active directory SAML SSO configuration issue with Django backend

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to set up SAML Single Sign-On (SSO) with my Django app, but I am getting an error when I try to login to my app.

I go to the app url, Microsoft processes the request (the url displays microsoft.loginonline.com/etc briefly), and then I get redirected to this page:

```
https://my-app.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback
```

which displays this error:

```
{"code":400,"message":"IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match keys: \nkid: '[PII is hidden]', \ntoken: '[PII is hidden]'."}
```

The reply url is set to:

```
https://my-app.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback
```

I did the set-up following both the Azure docs and following this documentation: https://django-auth-adfs.readthedocs.io, it's ostensibly working on my localhost, just not on the actual azure app service... I am unsure of what I am doing wrong, and the error message is not very informative for me as I am new to back-end programming and cloud.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As stated by you, you have configured SAML SSO with Django app in the backend and encountering the said error while logging in. As per the error reported, the ‘PII value is hidden’ due to which the signature keys couldn’t be validated by the AAD. So, you will need to add some strings to your ‘settings.py’ file to notify the Django web app the returned value of token from AAD. Please find the below strings to be added to the respective file: -
Please add the below string to AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS section in ‘settings.py’ file.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

After adding the above string to the said file, the app should work and so the SSO too.

Also, please find the below link to a similar thread for your reference: -

[JWT token authentication fails with message "PII is hidden"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55300231/jwt-token-authentication-fails-with-message-pii-is-hidden)

Thanks

Comment: This is in my settings.py: AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django_auth_adfs.backend.AdfsAuthCodeBackend',
    'django_auth_adfs.backend.AdfsAccessTokenBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;'
]

And I'm still getting the same error