# IDX20803: Swagger page error while using idserver4 on docker

Tags: docker, dns, identityserver4, docker-container, .net-6.0

We have 2 docker containers, 1 each for identity server and another for an application. I am able to authorize the swagger page but when I execute an end-point in the swagger page, I see *Internal Server 500 error*.

Below is the response while using edge dev-tools:
**Status 500 while SetCsrfCookie** //initiator abp.swagger.js

```
Request URL: https://mydomainname:8080/abp/Swashbuckle/SetCsrfCookie
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 500 
Remote Address: 10.0.0.3:8080
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

**Status 500 while calling https://mydomainname:8080/api/entity-name/entityname** //initiator swagger-ui-bundle.js:2

---

**Following error from container:**

```
[INF] Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://mydomainname:8080/abp/Swashbuckle/SetCsrfCookie - -
[ERR] Exception occurred while processing message.
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'.
```

---

Now I tried the below things after following a couple of suggestions:

1. Put both containers in same network in docker using --network.
2. Give network alias using --network-alias.

The problem I understand is that the application container cannot resolve the internal domain to itself.

The SetCsrfCookie method is not found at mydomainname:8080.
What I figure we need to do is to make sure the container is able to resolver mydomainname:8080 to itself, whose ip addr is 172.18.0.4.

I tried --add-host, --network-alias etc while running the container.
Currently we're resolving request to VM 10.0.0.3 (that has the container) to mydomainname by using the hosts file in our machine.

The issue i figure is when the container in the vm trying to resolve mydomainname to itself. How can we solve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable the `ShowPII` flag first to get an actual error message.

How this is done is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55869991/3936440).

In my case the URL used to fetch the discovery document was wrong but it could be really anything. The actual error message will give you a glue.

Comment: For me it was an issue with the certificate being unavailable. I added the certificate inside the container and the error disappeared. Thanks for the help :)